# Is it possible to collect audio data then publish audio data every 0.5 second?

Tags: go, hook, publish, audio-streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to collect audio data then publish audio data every 0.5 second?

I am using Go RTMP Server with https://github.com/yutopp/go-rtmp this package and it works well.

inside of function OnAudio(): this is function that processing of audio data, it receives data from OBS and DecodeAudioData and Publish to vlc player

this is original code of OnAudio()

```
func (h *Handler) OnAudio(timestamp uint32, payload io.Reader) error {
    var audio flvtag.AudioData
    if err := flvtag.DecodeAudioData(payload, &audio); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    flvBody := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if _, err := io.Copy(flvBody, audio.Data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    audio.Data = flvBody
    _ = h.pub.Publish(&flvtag.FlvTag{
        TagType:   flvtag.TagTypeAudio,
        Timestamp: timestamp,
        Data:      &audio,
    })

    return nil
}
```

this code receives audio data every 0.02 second and publish it.
I want to chage the code that colelct audio data until 0.5 second and publish audio data
so trying like this ...

```
func (h *Handler) OnAudio(timestamp uint32, payload io.Reader) error {

    var audio flvtag.AudioData
    if err := flvtag.DecodeAudioData(payload, &audio); err != nil {
        return err
    }
       // if flag == true, startTimeStamp Control
    if h.Flag == true {
        h.startTimeStamp = timestamp
        h.Buf.Reset()
    }
    h.Flag = false

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if _, err := io.Copy(buf, audio.Data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if audio.AACPacketType == 0 {
        audio.Data = buf
        tag := &flvtag.FlvTag{
            TagType:   flvtag.TagTypeAudio,
            Timestamp: h.startTimeStamp,
            Data:      &audio,
        }
        timestamp, (timestamp - h.startTimeStamp), buf.Len())
        _ = h.pub.Publish(tag)
        h.Flag = true
        return nil
    }

    h.Buf.Write(buf.Bytes())

        // collect audio data into h.Buf and then publish every 0.5 seconds
    if timestamp-h.startTimeStamp >= 500 {
        h.lastTimeStamp = timestamp
        audio.Data = h.Buf
        tag := &flvtag.FlvTag{
            TagType:   flvtag.TagTypeAudio,
            Timestamp: h.startTimeStamp,
            Data:      &audio,
        }

        _ = h.pub.Publish(tag)
        h.Flag = true
    }

    return nil
}
```

when I check the audio data size There is no Data loss but audio datas are breaking out.
Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied your change to the official `server_relay_demo` (see [this commit](https://github.com/ZekeLu/go-rtmp/commit/529f85e3f0dd03ef9fbe23ac1bb3d7b9c0ff0e6b)). Then built and run this demo:

```
go build -v -o server_relay_demo .
./server_relay_demo
```

Then I downloaded http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4, and publish it with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i ForBiggerBlazes.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/appname/stream
```

And finally play it with vlc:

```bash
$ vlc rtmp://localhost/appname/stream
VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.18-0-ge9eceaed4d)
[000055c1cc8f3b10] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
[tcp @ 0x7f84280045c0] RTMP packet size mismatch 14272640 != 5642
```

It failed to play with this error: `RTMP packet size mismatch 14272640 != 5642`.

Then I replaced `h.startTimeStamp` with `timestamp` (see [this commit](https://github.com/ZekeLu/go-rtmp/commit/fa3f793b2fbea3595d752268763a6e3a2f2ebad3)):

```golang
tag := &flvtag.FlvTag{
    TagType:   flvtag.TagTypeAudio,
    Timestamp: h.startTimeStamp,
    Data:      &audio,
}
```

It works with this change. Though the audio and the video are out of sync.

Please try this solution. If it still does not work, please provide a demo and a detail step by step guide to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I tried DefaultChunkSize: rtmp.MaxChunkSize, but still Audio cuts out at regular intervals in the VLC player.
Before publish flv tag data, i save the flv tag data and check data size, and there is no data loss comparing with original code. 
But, Audio cuts out at regular intervals in the VLC player.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks You're right. The timestamp seems to be the cause. and additionally I tried this  queuing each payload as an &flvtag.FlvTag.
additionally, I find that this package has Audio Latency, one or two seconds,
if i want to fix about audio latency, what parts do i obeserve?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why the audio and video are out of sync. So I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I am gonna solve it. Thank you for answering!!